# Making Gmail show filtered folder first instead of Inbox

Tags: gmail

Can I make a label tag filter and have that displayed instead of the inbox? I want my tasks to show up first.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `settings (the cog in the top right) -> labs` and enable `multiple inboxes`

Description of the lab feature:

> Add extra lists of emails in your Inbox to see even more important email at once. The new lists of threads can be labels, your starred messages, drafts or any search you want, configurable under Settings.